# Problem in solving ordinary differential equation in scilab

Tags: scilab

```
clf
clc

function dx=f(t,x)
    dx(1) = x(2)
    dx(2) = -B*(1-x^2)*x(2)-w*w*x(1)
endfunction

B = 5
w = 1
x0 = [10;100]
t = 0:0.01:10

x = ode(x0,0,t,f)
plot2d(t,x)
```

Now it shows the following problem in scilab console...

```
 at line     3 of function f   ( /Users/mottelet/so.sce line 7 )
in builtin                ode 
at line    15 of executed file /Users/mottelet/so.sce

Submatrix incorrectly defined.
ode: An error occurred in 'lsoda' subroutine.
```

Please tell me what did I do wrong and tell the solution.

Comment: Please copy the text instead of taking photos. I am unable to read the text on the second photo.

Comment: I did it for him before answering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in the code of function `f` at this line

```
    dx(2) = -B*(1-x^2)*x(2)-w*w*x(1)
```

because the expression `-B*(1-x^2)*x(2)` yields a vector and you try to assign it to a scalar container (here `dx(2)`). Maybe you wanted to write `-B*(1-x(1)^2)*x(2)` or `-B*(1-x(2)^2)*x(2)` (i.e. replace the first occurence of `x` by one of its components) ?

Comment: I wanted to write x(1)^2. And thanks for editing and answering.

Comment: In the future please take the time to copy/paste text of errors.